# AWS Athena: Unknown type: float

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I tried to  `CREATE TABLE xxx AS SELECT cast(1.0 as float) as my_float ...` but I got the error:

> TYPE_MISMATCH: line 1:15: Unknown type: float

When I check the [AWS Data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html) documentation and the `float` type does exist!

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part of this AWS doc mentions:

> use float in DDL statements like CREATE TABLE and real in SQL functions like SELECT CAST

Even if I was creating a table, I had to use `real` because I was casting:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx AS SELECT cast(1.0 as real) as my_float ...
```

The table created then had a DDL like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE xxx (
    my_float float,
    ...
)
```

as mentioned in the doc:

> Athena translates real and float types internally (see the [June 5, 2018](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-notes.html#release-note-2018-06-05) release notes).

I hope it will save time for some people.

Comment: I would never have figured this one out.....